# Using Google Sheets to create lists

Tags: google-sheets

Let's see if I can explain this in a comprehensible manner:

To make the administration around certain field days easier, I want to make a spreadsheet where class teachers can put in the names of their students. Next to the student's name, there will be a drop-down menu (I seem to have figured that one out).

The next thing I want is for Google Sheets to take those names and sort them into lists. So, all the students who chose "softball" will end up in list, and the ones who chose "golf" ends up on another, and so on.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzoVMk78s9ZUSDflN1Q0Dv2US3zBVeHaFjaL7Z__M1A/edit?usp=sharing

Check out this sheet, it should have your answers.
I have used data validation for the dropdowns and then transposed that into headers, with the FILTER formula to find matches.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I just need to figure out how to make the formula work across sheets.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work:

=OMFEL(Filter(query({7A!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;7B!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;7C!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;7D!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;8A!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;8B!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;8C!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;8D!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;9A!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;9B!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;9C!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B;9D!$A$2:$A, $B$2:$B})=A1)
)

Comment: I have modified the sheet. To make it work across sheets, add the sheet name and "!". If it is two or more words you need to enclose it. e.g.   'Sign Up'!    Volleyball!     'Class List'!